# Based on user selection, display brand models python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I want to display the models for the brand the user has inputted after it has been verified in the list. When I put the car_model_choice function outside car_brand_choice it shows the models but it shows the models regardless of user selection.

Since the variable needed (selection) is a local variable it can't be used anywhere else but it is what is needed to display the correct models. I tried using a return at the end of car_brand_choice but that ended the program.

I also thought maybe a matrix might help but not sure how that would work since there will be multiple models per one brand.

I will provide more code as needed also.

I apologize in advance if this question is duplicated but I could not find it anywhere.

```
def car_brand_choice(): 
    time.sleep(1.5)
    print "These are the car brands I can provide to you.\n"
    print "\n".join(car_brands)
    selection = raw_input("\nNow is your chance to pick which brand you want. ").title()
    print "You selected %s \n" %selection
    print "I have to verify your selection is valid.\n"
    time.sleep(10)
    if selection in car_brands:
        print "Valid selection. You may continue.\n"
        #Display brand models after verification
        car_model_choice()

else:
    print "Not valid selection."
    print "Go back and select a valid brand.\n"
    car_brand_choice()

def car_model_choice():
    print "Select your model."
    selection = "\n".join(kia_car)
    print selection
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Edit with price for each model**. Not sure I got your ideia/question, but you can have a dictionary of brand => models, and pass the brand as argument for model selection:

```
car_dict = {'brand1': ['brand1_model1', 'brand1_model2'], 
            'brand2': ['brand2_model1', 'brand2_model2'], 
            'brand3': ['brand3_model1', 'brand3_model2']}
```

There are different approaches, but here is one ideia:

```
price_dict = {'brand1_model1' => 20000, 'brand1_model2' => 22000,
              'brand2_model1' => 18000, 'brand2_model2' => 21000,
              'brand3_model1' => 19000, 'brand3_model2' => 24000}
```

Then,

```
def car_brand_choice(): 
    time.sleep(1.5)
    car_brands = car_dict.keys()
    print "These are the car brands I can provide to you.\n"
    print "\n".join(car_brands) # Show brands options
    selection = raw_input("\nNow is your chance to pick which brand you want. ").title()
    print "You selected %s \n" %selection
    print "I have to verify your selection is valid.\n"
    time.sleep(10)
    selection = selection.lower()
    if selection in car_brands:
        print "Valid selection. You may continue.\n"
        #Display brand models after verification
        car_model_choice(selection)
    else:
        print "Not valid selection."
        print "Go back and select a valid brand.\n"
        car_brand_choice()

def car_model_choice(brand):
   print "Select your model."
   for model in car_dict[brand]: # Show model options
       print model
   model_selection = raw_input("\nNow is your chance to pick which model you want. ").title()
   print "You selected a " + brand + " model " + model_selection + " by " + str(price_dict[model_selection])
```

Comment: That is what exactly what I was looking for. Would the same concept apply if I wanted to go even deeper, such as show pricing, etc.?

Comment: Yes, see my edit above, hope it helps. (Please, consider accepting my answer).